# How to batch save screenshots in paraview?

Tags: python, paraview

Does anyone know how to call paraview in batch mode and then save screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example script:

```
from paraview import simple
simple.Sphere()
simple.Show()
simple.Render()
simple.WriteImage("/tmp/foo.png")
```

Refer to the ParaView Python documentation for options available for WriteImage()

http://www.paraview.org/ParaView3/Doc/Nightly/www/py-doc/paraview.simple.html#paraview.simple.WriteAnimation

Comment: Documentation mentions that WriteImage is deprecated, use SaveScreenshot instead (starting Paraview v4.2)